# Electron 8.2.3 BrowserWindow in GC roots, but memory not released

Tags: memory-leaks, electron, garbage-collection

I am developing an electron app. When I close a BrowserWindow it takes a heap snapshot of browser process. The BrowserWindow is in the link of GC roots but the memory is not released.

[image]
<sub>(source: [bcebos.com](https://marx.cdn.bcebos.com/electron))</sub>

Comment: you'd need to post a minimal example that demonstrates this

Comment: Here is a demo https://github.com/MarxJiao/electron-demo

Comment: what OS are you running on? This doesn't run correctly for me, because the app quits before all the windows are created (because of your `app.quit()` call)

Comment: alright I flipped the `close` and `create` calls which worked. How are you loading the snapshot? It appears blank when I load the profile into Chrome Devtools -> Performance

Comment: [might](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21586) be related

Comment: could you also check if explicitly deleting the webcontents (`window.webContents.destroy()`) solves this?

Comment: Load the heapsnapshot here: Chrome Devtools -> Memory -> Load

Comment: window.webContents.destroy() got an error 'Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: Object has been destroyed'

Comment: are you destroying the webcontents before closing the window?

Comment: Yes. Right before `win.close()`.

Comment: nevermind then. I'm guessing the issue I linked to above is what's going on. Electron will likely have to fix this